# Android ViewPager2 library throwing Transactiontoolarge exception onpause event

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, transactiontoolargeexception

[image]I am getting TransactionTooLarge exception if page size = 50 and I press the home button. I checked the FragmentStateAdapter and found that 'saveState()' method is finalized.
Please help me how to resolve this.

In ViewPager it was overriden by me using below link-
https://medium.com/@mdmasudparvez/android-os-transactiontoolargeexception-on-nougat-solved-3b6e30597345

But no way in View pager2 library.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out @Ashish Agrawal?

Answer (score 1):

I had terrible random crash with my fragments.
The one megabyte limit is system wide, so it can crash at much lower thresholds.

I fixed the issue by stopping to use serialized objects and only passing integers into intents and fragment arguments.

Then fragments and activities can get the actual object from a repository using the integer id I gave to it.
It is faster and with insight it is a lot simpler.